# How can I import AWS Pinpoint in a Lambda index.js file

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-pinpoint

Recently I upgraded to Lambda Node.js 18.x. As part of that I was told, the correct way to get access to Pinpoint is by using the following statements in my index.js file.

import { Pinpoint } from '@aws-sdk/client-pinpoint';
const pinpoint = new Pinpoint({ region: 'us-east-1' });

I am doing all this from Lambda console in AWS.
When I test, I get the following Execution result.

Response
{
"errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
"errorMessage": "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module",
"trace": [
"Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module",
"    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1084:17)",
"    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)",
"    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",
"    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"
]
}

How can I fix this?